# Addressbar url gets all the posted data when preventing submission

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, spring-boot, post

The opened route is http://localhost:8080/clients. A modal containing a submit button is opened inside the page when clicking a button. I want to make a manual post when clicking the submit button :

```
<div id="modalAjoutClient" class="modal">
   <form id="frmClient">
       ....
       <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="submit" class="btn" id="btnValiderPopupAjoutClient">Valider</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn dismiss-modal">Annuler</button>
       </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Javascript side :

```
$("#btnValiderPopupAjoutClient").on("click", function(e) {
        $("#frmClient").attr('novalidate', 'novalidate');
        let videExist = [];
        if (document.getElementById("nom").value == "" || document.getElementById("nationalite").value == "") {
            videExist[0] = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById("nomFacturation").value == "" || document.getElementById("paysFacturation").value == "") {
            videExist[1] = true;
        }
        if (videExist.length > 0) {
            let onglet = -1;
            for(let v = 0 ; v < videExist.length ; v++) {
                if (videExist[v] === true) {
                    onglet = v;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (onglet != -1) {
                tabsModalClient[onglet].click();
                $("#frmClient").removeAttr('novalidate');
            }
        }
    });

    async function createClient() {
        let response = await fetch ( $("#API_URL").val()+'/clients', {
                                                                        method: 'POST',
                                                                        headers: {
                                                                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                                                        },
                                                                        body: JSON.stringify($("#frmClient").serializeJSON())
                                                                    }
                                    );
        let data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }

    $("#frmClient").on("submit", function(e) {
        if (e.target.checkValidity()) { // formulaire valide
            if ($("#frmClient #mode_").val() == "ajout") {
                createClient().then(data => {
                    $('#frmClient')[0].reset();
                    modalClient.style.display = "none";
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
            }
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The backend ( spring-boot quarkus ) route concerned is :

```
@Path("/clients")
@ApplicationScoped
public class ClientResource {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ClientResource.class);
    
    private final ClientService service;

    // Constructor
    @Inject
    public ClientResource(ClientService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(TMmcClient data) {
        try {
            var newData = service.create(data);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(newData).build();
        } catch (DataConstraintException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occured during client creation." + e.getStackTrace());
            Payload payload = new Payload("Invalid payload.",e.getMessage());
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(payload).build();
        }
    }   

    ...
    
}
```

The problem is at runtime after clicking the submit button then the addressbar shows all the fields posted with their value. So how to make the manual post so that the url stays to http://localhost:8080/clients ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior for the form is a GET request.

The `e.preventDefault();` inside the `if ($("#frmClient #mode_").val() == "ajout") {` is inside the callback function `createClient().then(data => {`. So, at the time when `createClient()` returns data the submit event is already done.

Place the `e.preventDefault();` before the conditional statement (now that both if and else will result in custom behavior).

```
$("#frmClient").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();        
  if (e.target.checkValidity()) { // formulaire valide
    if ($("#frmClient #mode_").val() == "ajout") {
      createClient().then(data => {
        $('#frmClient')[0].reset();
        modalClient.style.display = "none";
      });
    }
  }
});
```